# Proper way to remove Page from website

Tags: seo

I have a product page in my website which I have added 3 years before.

Now the product production was stopped and the product page was removed from website.

What I did is I started displaying message in the product page telling that the production of the product got stopped.

when some one searches in google for that products the product page which was removed from site shows up first in google search.

The page rank for the product page is also high.

I don't want the removed product page to be shown at the top of search result.

What is the proper method to remove a page from website so that it gets depicted by what ever google have indexed in its table.

Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

## Delete It

The proper way to remove a page from a site is to delete the actual file that is been returned to the user/bot when the page is requested. If the file is not on the webserver, any well configured webserver will return a 404 and the bot/spider will choose to remove that from the index in the next refresh.

## Redirect It

If you want to keep the good "google juice" or SERP ranking the page has, probably due to any inbound links from external sites, you'd be best to set your websever to do a 302 redirect to a similar (updated product).

## Keep and convert

However, if the page is doing so well that it ranks #1 for searches to the entire site, you need to use this to your advantage. Leave the bulk of the copy on the page the same, but highlight to the viewer that the product no longer exists and provide some helpful options to the user instead: tell them about a newer, better product, tell them why it's no longer available, tell them where they can go to get support if they already have the discontinued product.

Answer (score 0):

I am completely agree with above suggestion and want to add just one point.

If you want to remove that page from Google Search Result; just login to Google webmaster tool (you must have verified that website in Google webmaster tool) and add that particular page for index removal request.

Google will de-index that page and it will be removed from Google search rankings.